# PHPUnit deprecation warning fails test

Tags: php, exception, configuration, phpunit, deprecated

I'm using PHPUnit 4.8 on a PHP 5.3.29 install. Some of the code in our application makes use of the deprecated `mysql_*` functionality, and PHPUnit converts the deprecation notices of these instances to exceptions and in turn fails those specific testcases.

Now I've already included the `convertErrorsToExceptions="false"` in the config.xml but this doesn't seem to help as it's still happening.

Can anyone help shed some light on what might be happening here?

Cheers!

**EDIT**: Added example files on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d688406733a6bc84d7120efa6564409e)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `convertErrorsToExceptions="false"` configuration option only controls the conversion of `E_ERROR` to exceptions. A deprecation is represented as `E_DEPRECATED`, though.

A [configuration option is missing for controlling the conversion of `E_DEPRECATED` to exceptions](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2670). This will be added in PHPUnit 6.2. This will not be backported to PHPUnit 4.8, the version of PHPUnit you are using, as that version has reached its end of life.

In your bootstrap script you can set `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated::$enabled = false;`, though, which will disable the conversion of `E_DEPRECATED` to exceptions.

Comment: I upgraded to PHPUnit 6.5.14 and I still get exit code 1 if there are any deprecation notices...

Answer (score 6):

if you are looking solution for Symfony 3.1 and higher versions, the answer is

```xml
<env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a Symfony/Drupal related solution, a quick way can be to set the env variable in your test file(I needed it because deprecation warnings were coming from a third party repo).

```
putenv('SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last versions (with PHP namespaces), this has become:

```php
\PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Deprecated::$enabled = false;
```